# Error with Devise Gem when Signing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, devise

I'm getting an error when signing up using Devise. I am switching from a session-based authentication system I previously set up to Devise.

I installed Devise and have this in my model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable,  :registerable, :confirmable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

This is my migration:

```
class AddDeviseUserTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.confirmable
      t.encryptable

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_column :users, :name, :string

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

I also have this in my routes:

```
root :to => "videos#index"
devise_for :users
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

The error I get when signing up is:

```
NameError in Devise/registrationsController#create

undefined local variable or method `encrypt_new_password' for #<User:0x1032a8cb8>
```

Here is the full trace:

```
activemodel (3.0.4) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:39:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in `save'
devise (1.3.4) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:16:in `create'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `_run__1732029701__process_action__1623385099__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:35:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:89:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `encrypt_new_password` method in the Devise source code so I suspect this method was left behind when you switched from your previous authentication system to Devise. I would search through your application code for the string `encrypt_new_password` and see what you can find.

Probably something in your User model that needs more cleanup. In particular look for any obsolete before and/or after callback in your User model since the failure occurs during a call to `User#save`.

Comment: On the command line: `cd <your_rails_project>` then `find . -name "*.rb" | xargs grep "encrypt_new_password"`. Not a Textmate user so can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: yeah it was an obsolete callback